# Ever increasing Disk space for a cache in ignite storage directory

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We are using ignite 2.12 with persistence enabled along with full sync - replicated mode.
There is a cache whose data ranges from few Kilobytes to few Megabytes.
Once a particular cache entry is worked upon, we remove that entry from cache. The cache goes through a large number of reads/writes parallely.

But what we have observed is, the disk space utilized by the cache keeps on increasing. I had expected the disk space to be reused - (deleted cache entries disk partitions) for new cache entries being inserted , but this is not happening.

Any reason for this behavior and any solution to avoid such problems?

Answer (score 0):

Entry removal doesn't reclaim the file size, instead, the allocated space is reserved for reuse and never shrinks itself. There is a [persistence defragmentation](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/defragmentation#persistence-defragmentation) feature in GridGain, and most likely Apache Ignite, that explains the concept and might help you to reduce disk usage.

In the meantime, `cache#destroy` should do the trick as well.

Comment: but if the space should be reused, it means that the used storage size should not increase for some time after deletion. but after deleting a huge amount of data, the occupied space only increases. we expected disk usage to stabilize when using TTL, but this is not happening